# How does AlertListener work on Blackberry API 5.0?

Tags: api, blackberry

Does the AlertListener interface works globally on all alerts on the blackberry device, or does it only work with alerts generated by your application?

In other words, can I use this interface to listen when the phone generates any alert (ie. SMS, Email, Blackberry Messenger, third party app alerts, etc.)?

Let me know,

Regards

Comment: Just a quick note - this API isn't new to 5.0, it's been around since 3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If it's like other listeners such as FileSystemListener then it should work for alerts generated outside of your application as well.  The best way to find out is it try it!  :)

Comment: The issue is that I dont yet have a device to try it on, I am running the app on the simulator.

So far I have not figured out how to produce an alert on the simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately I think all you can simulate in the simulator is incoming voice calls.